# How do I assign Cloud Composer DAGs to run on specific Node Pools?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Cloud Composer (Apache Airflow) on Google Cloud. Some of our processes require more resources than what's available on Composer's default node pool, so I've created an additional node pool within our cluster. The resource-intensive DAG's use the KubernetesPodOperator and specifically target the special node pool through the `affinity={ nodeAffinity...}` attribute.

My issue is that since creating the new node pool, I've noticed that ALL of my workloads are being scheduled on this new pool. How can I keep my normal workloads running on the default pool, while reserving the new node pool for special use cases?

Here is an example of KubernetesPodOperator definition that targets the special pool. The regular KubernetesPodOperator don't have the affinity attribute filled out:

```
KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
            image="image_name",
            image_pull_policy='Always',
            name="example_name",
            task_id="example_name",
            get_logs=True,
            affinity={
                'nodeAffinity': {
                    'requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution': {
                        'nodeSelectorTerms': [{
                            'matchExpressions': [{
                                'key': 'cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool',
                                'operator': 'In',
                                'values': ['datascience-pool']
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            is_delete_operator_pod=True,
            dag=dag)
```

Comment: How to identify resource-intensive process and normal process, are they belong to different DAG node? Different DAG node can be constructed with various `affinity` options.

Comment: I've created two different node pools and am using the affinity options. The problem is that regular workloads are no longer being scheduled on the default node pool.

For example, if I don't specify affinity on a KubernetesPodOperator...the default behavior is targeting my new node pool instead of the default.

Comment: It seems Cloud Composer has some implicit schedule strategy. Can you provide your KubernetesPodOperator construction params?

Comment: Modified the original post to include an example of KubernetesPodOperator definition. The regular workloads don't use the affinity attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The KubernetesPodOperator does not have any default affinity preferences, so the scheduling decision for your normal workloads to have ended up in the new node pool were made by the Kubernetes scheduler. To avoid this, you will now have to set affinity on all instances of KubernetesPodOperator (which you can make somewhat less painful by using `default_args` and the `apply_defaults` Airflow decorator).

At least as of versions of Cloud Composer up to v1.8.3, the Composer system pods will always run in the node pool `default-pool`. Therefore, you can use this to ensure the pods run in the Composer node pool instead of a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a work around but I have solved this issue by assigning affinity to all of the tasks. Tasks requiring high-cpu or high-memory are assigned to respective node pool and default tasks are assigned to default-pool. This resolves the issue, I have tested in many flows.